# Exclude folders from VS one-click Publish

Tags: deployment, visual-studio-2017, publish

I have set up a one-click publish and am trying to exclude certain folders from publishing.

In my project properties I have selected *Only files needed to run this application* within *Items to deploy sections* and in the Publish profile xml file I have added the following to the PropertyGroup tag:

```
<ExcludeFoldersFromDeployment>
  App_Plugins;Content;media;umbraco;umbraco_client
</ExcludeFoldersFromDeployment>
```

However it doesn't work correctly. So far `App_Plugins`, `umbraco`, `umbraco_client` and part of `media` (here some subforlders published some not) folders have been included in the Publish despite the above settings while `Content` folder has not been published.

Am I doing it wrong?